# upload collection view images into server using swift

Tags: swift2, uicollectionview, http-post

I'm developing an app which has UICollectionView as like #zhangao0086/DKImagePickerController# example in Github. Now i need to upload the displayed UICollectionviewCell images into server. Can any one suggest me the right tuts for uploading. Thanks in advance.

UICollectionView code as follows:

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let asset = self.assets![indexPath.row]
    var cell: UICollectionViewCell?
    var imageView: UIImageView?

    if asset.isVideo {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellVideo", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    } else {
        cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("CellImage", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        imageView = cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(1) as? UIImageView
    }

    if let cell = cell, imageView = imageView {
        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
        let tag = indexPath.row + 1
        cell.tag = tag
        asset.fetchImageWithSize(layout.itemSize.toPixel(), completeBlock: { image, info in
            if cell.tag == tag {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        })
    }

    return cell!
}
```

uploading the image into server

```
func barButtonItemClicked(barButtonItem: UIBarButtonItem)
{
    let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://moneymonkey.tokiiyo.com/api/signature");

    let typeItem: InsuranceType = InsuranceManager.sharedInstance.TypeArray[0]
    let compItem: Companies = InsuranceManager.sharedInstance.CompArray[0]

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:myUrl!);
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST";

    let param = [
        "api_key"  : "AiK58j67",
        "api_secret"    : "a#9rJkmbOea90-",
        "phone"    : "\(mobile)",
        "policy_type"   :   "\(typeItem.name)",
        "company"   :   "\(compItem.cname)"
    ]

    print("Policy_type: \(typeItem.name)")
    let boundary = generateBoundaryString()

    request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(?)  //here what imageView 

    if(imageData==nil)  { return; }

    request.HTTPBody = createBodyWithParameters(param, filePathKey: "file", imageDataKey: imageData!, boundary: boundary)


    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        data, response, error in

        if error != nil {
            print("error=\(error)")
            return
        }

        // You can print out response object
        print("******* response = \(response)")

        // Print out reponse body
        let responseString = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        print("****** response data = \(responseString!)")
        do{

            _ = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
            });
        }
        catch
        {

            // report error
            print("Oops!! Something went wrong\(error)")
        }
    }

    task.resume()

}

func createBodyWithParameters(parameters: [String: String]?, filePathKey: String?, imageDataKey: NSData, boundary: String) -> NSData {
    let body = NSMutableData();

    if parameters != nil {
        for (key, value) in parameters! {
            body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
            body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"\r\n\r\n")
            body.appendString("\(value)\r\n")
        }
    }

    let filename = "image.png"

    let mimetype = "image/png"

    body.appendString("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(filePathKey!)\"; filename=\"\(filename)\"\r\n")
    body.appendString("Content-Type: \(mimetype)\r\n\r\n")
    body.appendData(imageDataKey)
    body.appendString("\r\n")



    body.appendString("--\(boundary)--\r\n")

    return body
}

func generateBoundaryString() -> String {
    return "Boundary-\(NSUUID().UUIDString)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

J

you can use Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

Use like this :

```
Alamofire.upload(.POST, "YourURl", file: YourFile)
         .progress { bytesWritten, totalBytesWritten, totalBytesExpectedToWrite in
             print(totalBytesWritten)

             // This closure is NOT called on the main queue for performance
             // reasons. To update your ui, dispatch to the main queue.
             dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                 print("Total bytes written on main queue: \(totalBytesWritten)")
             }
         }
         .responseJSON { response in
             debugPrint(response)
         }
```